# Applescript to Paste clipboard text into Messages and send to email

Tags: applescript

The title says it all really.

Im new to applescripts and I'm hoping someone will be able to explain how to

Paste the clipboard text into Messages and send to a user using a applescript.

Also if you know how to send an image attachment instead of the clipboard text that would be amazing, and I would really appreciate it

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
set clipContent to (the clipboard as text)

tell application "Mail"
    set myMessage to make new outgoing message at the beginning of outgoing messages with properties {subject:"Clipboard Content"}

    tell myMessage to make new to recipient at beginning of to recipients with properties {address:"first@email.com, second@email.com"}
    set myMessage's content to clipContent
    set myMessage's visible to true
    activate

    -- Uncomment the line below to send the message
    --send myMessage
end tell
```